# Android Maven project using Volley: NullPointerException

Tags: android, maven, nullpointerexception, android-volley

I've got a Maven project that I'm trying to use Volley with. This is my first time using either. I added Volley to my local repository, and I added the dependency in my project's pom.xml file. Everything compiles nicely, but whenever I try to make a new Request object, I get a NullPointerException on the super class Request object. Any help?

EDIT: Here's my stack trace

```
8-29 22:14:58.830: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(696): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lhs.app/com.lhs.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.volley.Request.<init>(Request.java:129)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.<init>(JsonRequest.java:58)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.<init>(JsonObjectRequest.java:47)
    at com.lhs.app.MainActivity.startRequest(MainActivity.java:35)
    at com.lhs.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
```

Comment: Since it compiled, it has nothing to do with maven. For the NPE look at the cogcat it tells you exactly in which file and line it happens. We cant help without seeing your code and logcat.

Comment: That stack trace was taken from logcat. Unfortunately, there's nothing else around it which says anything related. It implies that the cause is somewhere in the Volley library, but I'm not sure how that would have happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided I have the same version of Volley, the NPE happens in this line:

```
mDefaultTrafficStatsTag = TextUtils.isEmpty(url) ? 0: Uri.parse(url).getHost().hashCode();
```

So it seems you are using an `url` without a host part.

Comment: Yes. I found this last night, too. I was using a url of "www.myurl.com" instead of "http://www.myurl.com". I guess I assumed the library would assume an "http://".

Comment: I've run into that as well. If you change it so it doesn't crash when the URL is malformed there, you will actually get a descriptive error message instead of a null pointer exception.